# Не совсем подходящий раздел для текста в справке "Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы"

Tags: дефект, справка

В разделе справки [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  есть такой текст:

> **Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы**
>
> Ваше простое искреннее «спасибо» очень ценно, но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего — проголосуйте за ответы, которые вам больше всего помогли, и, по возможности, отвечайте на вопросы других участников.

Но ведь это не рассказывает о том, как написать хороший ответ. Это скорее рассказывает [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Хмм... Подождите-ка, а разве за ответы надо говорить спасибо? Серьезно, по-моему, когда я читал правила, там рекомендовалось не давать бессмысленные комментарии типа "спасибо", а просто голосовать вверх!

Comment: @МаксимФисман Вы правы, не надо.